# Good alternative to environment modules for windows?

Tags: environment, environment-modules

In the past I have used environment modules extensively in Unix based systems. The tool proved very usefull since we had many different projects each of them using a potentially different set of tools.

I am now however stuck with a windows machine and need to make the most of it. Does anybody know of a good alternative to environment modules for windows? I am basically looking for a tool that let's me manipulate the PATH (or $env:PATH in windows powershell) environment variable without having to touch it directly.

Comment: Nothing at all?

Comment: I'm also curious. Have you found a solution to this? I'm trying to use the MKL library in fortran and this link recommends using environment modules https://www2.cisl.ucar.edu/resources/computational-systems/cheyenne/code-development-support/math-kernel-library-mkl

Answer (score 1):

You can install environment modules on windows as well. The instructions are in the repository https://github.com/cea-hpc/modules/blob/master/INSTALL-win.txt

Basically you have to install active state tcl and copy the source files.
I use this and it works quite well.